# Add path operation to multiple shape layers

Tags: after-effects

I have multiple shape layers, and I want to add `Wiggle Paths` to all of them.
One way of course is to manually add to each of them.
Is there a way to add it to all of them at once? Specially is there a way to control them all in one place? so if I wanted to change the Wiggle parameters (like size, speed, correlation ...) I can change them all at once?

Comment: Thanks @poor . I didn't know you can add "path operations" to Null layers. let me try it.

Comment: Ah, I was also thinking I may find an effect to do the same thing

Comment: The only way is to drive your values by **Slider Control's** created on a _Null_, but this could take ca. 20min to setup.

Comment: I like the idea of a "slider control" why don't you put it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Expression Slider Controls to drive **multiple Shape Layer Wiggle Path Values**.

Here is an example of driving `Size` and `Detail` values of the `Wiggle Path Property` on **6 Shape Layers** with 2 created **Slider Controls** on a seperate `Null Layer`:

[image]

Note: To save time, it's a good idea to create **one shape layer first**, set it up as described below and **duplicate it afterwards** to maintain the expression links.

[image]

1. Create a `Shape Layer` and a `Null Object`
2. Add `Wiggle Path Property` to the `Shape Layer`
3. Add a `Slider Control` to the `Null` **for every value** you need for animation *(size, speed, correlation ...)* and name it like these for a better organization
4. Select the `Null` and go to *Effect > Expression Control > Slider Control*
5. Open up the **properties of the both layers** by clicking on the small arrow  <kbd>></kbd>  right beside the layer's name to see the values of the `Wiggle Path` and the newly created `slider control` at the same time
6. Holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd> while clicking on the **stop watch** of a `Wiggle Path Value` like the `Size` or `Detail`, this automatically will insert an **expression**
7. Use the **expression pick whip** and drag it onto the predefined Slider Control of the `Null` before to link/parent it, for e.g. the **Size of Wiggle Paths**, this should create something like: `thisComp.layer("Name of the Null").effect("Size")("Name of Slider Control")`
8. **Repeat the process of parenting** the `Wiggle Path Values` to the `Sliders` as long as all needed values are parented to slider controls correctly
9. If you duplicate the `Shape Layer` with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> now, **all expressions will retained** for the duplicated layers

Comment: @Ali Cleaned up the answer, added a screenshot and a gif for better understanding.